# For Loop and Foreach continous loop?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am trying to place all Column Values of a `DataTable` as a `CheckBox` in a panel.

But the problem is I keep on having the same loop. I have limited the array loop depending on the `Column.Count` but it's still looping.

[Do note that there are ***tabs*** (they are **sheets** from an Excel file I've imported).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yFfF.png)

Here is a visual representation of my problem.

[image]

I want to cut it down until F19 and end the loop.

### Here is my code:

---

```
  int dynamicHeight = 0;
        int padding = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                    CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];
                    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
                    chk[i].Name = column.ColumnName;
                    chk[i].Text = column.ColumnName;
                    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
                    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
                    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
                    dynamicHeight += 20;
                    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
                    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
                    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
                    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
                    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
                    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
                    //panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can't seem to do it. If I remove the `foreach`, I just get checkboxes named 1-19. :/

Comment: Same with foreach, I don't how to reference the column names to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code for adding check boxes is running `dt.Columns.Count * dt.Columns.Count` times, ideally it should run only `dt.Columns.Count` times to get the desired output.

Without changing much of your implemented code, following should work in your case.

```
 CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];
 for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                chk[i] = new CheckBox();
                chk[i].Name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                chk[i].Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
                chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
                panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
                dynamicHeight += 20;
                panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
                panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
                chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
                chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
                panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
                panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
            }
```

OR

```
int i = 0;
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{

    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].Name = column.ColumnName;
    chk[i].Text = column.ColumnName;
    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    dynamicHeight += 20;
    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;

    i++;
    //panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);
}
```

Comment: There's no sense in using `foreach` if you then have to add an index. Just use the `for` one.

Comment: I just had trouble referencing the datacolumn. Little did I know that I just had to use `dt.Columns[I].ColumnName`.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create the array once, and you only need to iterate through it once.

```
int dynamicHeight = 0;
int padding = 10;

CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[dt.Columns.Count];

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var column = dt.Columns[i];
    chk[i] = new CheckBox();
    chk[i].Name = column.ColumnName;
    chk[i].Text = column.ColumnName;
    chk[i].AutoCheck = true;
    chk[i].Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20 + padding + dynamicHeight, 40, 22);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    dynamicHeight += 20;
    panelCol.Size = new Size(120, dynamicHeight);
    panelCol.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
    chk[i].Location = new Point(0, dynamicHeight);
    chk[i].Size = new Size(120, 21);
    panelCol.BackColor = Color.White;
    panelCol.AutoScroll = true;
    //panelCol.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size (0, 1200);
}
```

Actually, I don't think you even need the array, unless you're doing something with it later. You could probably remove it and just replace every instance of `chk[i]` with `checkBox`.